# Параллельный вызов boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost.python

Пытаюсь из кода на python, распараллеленного с помощью ThreadPoolExecutor вызвать код на C++. Создается впечатление, что в момент входа в C++ функцию все питоновские потоки замораживаются. Пример:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::this_thread;
using namespace boost::python;

void foo(int i)
{
    cout<<"Enter " << " foo("<<i<<") (c++) thread: " << get_id() << endl;
    sleep_for(  seconds(2) );
    cout<<"Exit  " << " foo("<<i<<") (c++) thread: " << get_id() << endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( test_py_async )
{
    def("foo", &foo);
}
```

python:

```
import test_py_async
import concurrent.futures

N=8

def foo(i):
    print( f"Enter  foo({i}) (py)")
    test_py_async.foo(i)
    print( f"Exit   foo({i}) (py)")
    return i

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:

    print("submit tasks:")
    futures=[ executor.submit( foo, i ) for i in range(N) ]

    print("wait for tasks:")
    results=[ future.result() for future in futures ]

    print(f"results: {results}")

print(f"exit ThreadPoolExecutor")
assert( results == [ i for i in range(N) ] )
```

вывод:

```
submit tasks:
Enter  foo(0) (py)
Enter  foo(0) (c++) thread: 11796
Exit   foo(0) (c++) thread: 11796
Enter  foo(1) (py)
Enter  foo(1) (c++) thread: 16580
Exit   foo(1) (c++) thread: 16580
Exit   foo(0) (py)
Enter  foo(2) (py)
Enter  foo(2) (c++) thread: 20240
Exit   foo(2) (c++) thread: 20240
Enter  foo(3) (py)
Exit   foo(1) (py)
Enter  foo(3) (c++) thread: 11796
Exit   foo(3) (c++) thread: 11796
Exit   foo(2) (py)
Enter  foo(4) (py)
Enter  foo(4) (c++) thread: 17568
Exit   foo(4) (c++) thread: 17568
Enter  foo(6) (py)
Enter  foo(6) (c++) thread: 19672
Exit   foo(6) (c++) thread: 19672
Enter  foo(5) (py)
Enter  foo(7) (py)
Enter  foo(7) (c++) thread: 16580
Exit   foo(7) (c++) thread: 16580
wait for tasks:
Exit   foo(3) (py)
Exit   foo(6) (py)
Exit   foo(7) (py)
Exit   foo(4) (py)
Exit   foo(5) (c++) thread: 16804
Exit   foo(5) (py)
results: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
exit ThreadPoolExecutor
```

Из лога видно, что вызовы c++ не пересекаются по времени выполнения ни с другими вызовами c++ , ни с питоновским кодом, хотя вызовы действительно производятся из разных потоков. Что я делаю нетак?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потоки python действительно в каком-то смысле замораживаются на время работы кода расширения, и причина тому – [GIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock)

Поток, в котором выполняется функция `foo`, захватывает `GIL`, и не отпускает его пока выполнение функции не завершится.

Если бы ваш код вызывал `sleep` из модуля `time`, или обращался к специфичным для python процедурам ввода/вывода, или иным образом взаимодействовал с интерпретатором, `GIL` в какой-то момент мог быть освобожден, давая возможность другим потокам полноценно работать.

Освободить его можно и вручную, обрамив ваш код специальными макросами.

```cpp
Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
sleep_for(  seconds(2) );
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

Примерно то же самое происходит и в [`time.sleep`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/timemodule.c#L1872)

Такой код не должен взаимодействовать с объектами python и/или обращаться к `API`.
Подробнее это описано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock)

```
submit tasks:
Enter  foo(0) (py)
Enter  foo(0) (c++) thread: 140388371265280
Enter  foo(1) (py)
Enter  foo(1) (c++) thread: 140388362872576
Enter  foo(2) (py)
Enter  foo(2) (c++) thread: 140388354479872
Enter  foo(3) (py)
Enter  foo(3) (c++) thread: 140388346087168
Enter  foo(4) (py)
Enter  foo(4) (c++) thread: 140388337694464
Enter  foo(5) (py)
Enter  foo(5) (c++) thread: 140387985389312
Enter  foo(6) (py)
Enter  foo(6) (c++) thread: 140387976996608
Enter  foo(7) (py)
Enter  foo(7) (c++) thread: 140387968603904
wait for tasks:
Exit   foo(0) (c++) thread: 140388371265280
Exit   foo(0) (py)
Exit   foo(1) (c++) thread: 140388362872576
Exit   foo(1) (py)
Exit   foo(2) (c++) thread: 140388354479872
Exit   foo(2) (py)
Exit   foo(3) (c++) thread: 140388346087168
Exit   foo(3) (py)
Exit   foo(4) (c++) thread: 140388337694464
Exit   foo(4) (py)
Exit   foo(5) (c++) thread: 140387985389312
Exit   foo(5) (py)
Exit   foo(6) (c++) thread: 140387976996608
Exit   foo(6) (py)
Exit   foo(7) (c++) thread: 140387968603904
Exit   foo(7) (py)
results: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
exit ThreadPoolExecutor
```